explore use of types with roslyn
I need to detect the use of some types and their properties. Types are in external assemblies always. I need to identify their use on current code. ex:
using MyCompany.MyTypes;
namespace TestProject
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public Car GetCar(Parking v)
    {
       return v.slots[0].vehicule;
    }
  }
}

Given the sample code above, I need to list types and properties in namespace "MyCompany.MyTypes" which is external to code, as follow:

type: MyCompany.MyTypes.Parking
type: MyCompany.MyTypes.Slot (as v.slots is List< Slot>)
property MyCompany.MyTypes.Slot.vehicule
type: MyCompany.MyTypes.Car

I'm iterating over projects and documents but only local namespaces and types are available using SemanticModel.
Is there any Tree of Referenced Types available in semanticModel ?

You need to create a SyntaxWalker and grab all the types you want. Google it :)
